# Custom arguments in Flask-Restless?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

Flask-Restless only accepts arguments that are columns defined in a SQLAlchemy model. I want to take something like `blue green` and store it in two columns `primary_color` and `secondary_color`.

Right now, I am POSTing the data as `primary_color` (an allowed field) and using a `postprocessor` to split it into `primary_color` and `secondary_color`.

Is it possible to do something cleaner and more semantic, like POST a `colors` field and then process it afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Request preprocessors](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors) are run *before* validating the POST data against the model.

Set a preprocessor on the API for  `POST` requests that parses any `colors` key, altering the `data` dictionary in-place:

```
def preprocess_colors(data):
    colors = data.pop('colors', None)
    if colors is not None:
        # set primary and secondary colors
        data['primary_color'] = get_primary_color(color)
        data['secondary_color'] = get_secondary_color(colors)
```

You do need to remove the `colors` key from the dictionary to prevent Flask-Restless from complaining about the key being there.

A postprocessor could never have worked here; these are only called to alter the returned response *after* the new instance has been created already.

Alternatively, create a [SQLAlchemy hybrid attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) on your model named `colors` that translates colors into primary and secondary colors in a setter.